# NodeJS Javascript piece code running on Windows but not on Linux

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux

I am particularly new to NodeJS and Javascript and have created a small web Application. I have my code running on Windows machine seamlessly. However, When I tried running it on a Linux VM it blocked at a point with no error or Exceptions thrown.

I discovered there was a line which actually caused a blockage in Linux, commented it out and the code continued from there on limiting the Application's functionality which greatly depends on that line with the other independent parts being functional.

```
....
var localEntry = entry.split('\\')
if(!localEntry)
localEntry = entry.split('/')

localEntry = localEntry[localEntry.length -1]

this.scripts[extn][localEntry].day1Vars = searchedVars[entry].day1Vars
}
```

I was extremely puzzled to find the exact same code running seamlessly on a Windows machine and blocking on a Linux vm due to a single line of code and am wondering how that could be ? The line which is responsible for such behavior is : 
    `this.scripts[extn][localEntry].day1Vars = searchedVars[entry].day1Vars`

My expectation is code on Node.js is platform independent and the thought of a line of code causing such difference is revolting.
I am using Windows 10 and RHEL 6.9 with 8GB of ram in both.

Could someone guide me if I am missing something or what has gone wrong?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

As requested by folks here, Sample values(on Windows) :

```
entry : "d:\NodeProjects\BApp\uploads\bp\bp\scripts\nodejs\set-nodejs-root.sh"
localEntry : "set-nodejs-root.sh"
```

Comment: give and example of `entry` and  `localEntry`

Comment: I think Mark is on the correct path, your condition should be based on the environment. It works for windows because you have set `var localEntry = entry.split('\\')` and I don't see that `localEntry` will ever be false.

Comment: Well, It still doesn't answers why an error or exception is not thrown on that line I mentioned above and Node sits there doing nothing for perhaps eternity. Could you answer that behaviour?

Comment: I am checking if localEntry is empty or not. Not necessarily false @EternalHour

Answer (score 0):

When you specify a path under windows you have to use "\"
Linux uses "/" for path

Comment: Thank you for answering. I thought that initially but shouldn't NodeJS throw an exception or error? It sits there silently doing nothing.

Comment: maybe you will find your answer here: 
https://shapeshed.com/writing-cross-platform-node/

Answer (score 0):

Its better to check what is the environment.
For example you should split in:

ubuntu `.split("/")`

windows `.split("\\")`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are working with paths, the best recommendation here is to use the path module to handle those routes for you:

https://nodejs.org/api/path.html

Here is a good explanation on how to handle routes for both systems:

https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_windows_vs_posix

I would use something like

https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_parse_path

To parse the paths correctly or if you need to construct paths you can use:

https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths

Check all different options there, I am 99% sure that you will find the proper method for your use case